# Will casting an aura on a creature with heroic trigger the heroic ability?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'll admit we've had a lot of trouble with the [Battlewise Hoplite](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Battlewise%20Hoplite) the last few games and what affects it and what doesn't. If he has a [Battlewise Hoplite](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Battlewise%20Hoplite)
in play and I play a [Crippling Blight](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Crippling%20Blight) does his [Battlewise Hoplite](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Battlewise%20Hoplite) get a +1/+1 counter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroic only triggers when "you" (the controller of the creature with heroic) cast a spell. So no, your opponent's [Battlewise Hoplite](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Battlewise%20Hoplite) will not trigger if you cast [Crippling Blight](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Crippling%20Blight) on it.

Aura spells do always target when cast, so it will trigger heroic if you cast an aura spell and target a creature *that you control* with heroic.

> 303.4a An Aura spell requires a target, which is defined by its enchant ability.

Comment: Er, I think OP's situation is if a player casts Crippling Blight on another player's Battlewise Hoplite.

Comment: @HaoYe I missed/forgot that Heroic only triggers when you cast a spell, not when any spell is cast. Will edit.